# How to sort a gridview - Icollection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

I Have a gridview bound on a Icollection. I need to sort this gridview so I tried to :

- set the AllowSorting attribute on true
- the SortExpression of my BoundFields

But when I click on the headers of my grid I got and exception saying the event is not handled... So I added an eventHandler method but I don't know what to put in this method.
I tried this but of course it didn't work (recursive)

```
protected void MyGrid_OnSorting(object sender, GridViewEventArgs e)
{ this.mygrid.Sort(e.SortExpression, e.SortDirection); }
```

I can't use linq (Frmwk 2.0) and it's not my application so I can't change too many things.
Is there another kind of collection or list which can be sorted with a SortExpression and SortDirection and bound a griview ?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to sort the data prior to it's assignment to the `ICollection<>`.  What is the source?

Comment: Or bind the ICollection to a DataView first, then you can sort that.

Comment: the source is a method which returns a ICollection too :( and to set a dataview I need a datatable but I dont have datatables in the program. Its not a very clean architecture...

Answer (score 0):

Have you added

```
OnSorting="MyGrid_OnSorting"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I had to convert the Icollection to a Datatable. If it can help...